# Equivalence between two definitions of measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am currently in a course in Analysis and I am starting to study measurable sets.
I have been discussing some of this stuff with a colleague from another university, and I have found that the definitions of measurable set that he uses and the one that I have been given by my proffesor are totally different.
Moreover, I have been searching on the internet in order to find an equivalence between both definitions, and, far from getting to that equivalence, I have found that my proffesor's definition doesn't even appear anywhere!
I have been struggling to find the equivalence for myself, but I haven't been able to do it by myself.
I give you both definitions, my colleague's definition (that I have found that is everyone's definition):

A set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is measurable if:$$\lambda^{*}(A)=\lambda^{*}(A\cap E)+\lambda^{*}(A\backslash E)$$ $\forall A\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $\lambda^{*}$ denotes the outer measure.

And the definition I have been given in my course:

A set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is measurable if:$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists (F \textrm{ closed set} \wedge G \textrm{ open set}) : F\subseteq E \subseteq G \wedge \lambda^{*}(G\backslash F)<\epsilon$$
where $\lambda^{*}$ denotes the outer measure.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What you call everyone's definition works in a very general setting, requiring just an outer measure. Your professor's definition presupposes also a topology, since it refers to open sets and closed sets. When a topology is available and the outer measure is suitably related to the topology, the two definitions agree; in particular, they agree for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. Personally, I've found your professor's version very useful not only for proofs but for intuition: Measurable sets can be well approximated by closed subsets and open supersets.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much for your quick response! Do you know any source where I can look more carefully on how this equivalence is true in the case of  working with $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have my analysis textbooks handy, so I can't verify where this material is covered, but I think I learned it from the book "Real and Abstract Analysis" by Hewitt and Stromberg (mainly because that's where I learned most of measure theory when preparing for qualifying exams). I think the key phrase to google is probably "Radon measure".

Comment: Thank you very much again!